# Effects of acceleration and gravity on proper time

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, acceleration, observers, time-dilation

Let's consider the effects of gravity and acceleration on proper time of an observer (yes, I want to know how the equivalence principle works).

First situation: a spaceship with rocket engine stays stationary at height $R$ up above a planet of mass $M$. The Schwarzschild metric reads: $$ds^2=\left(1-2\frac{GM}{rc^2}\right)c^2dt^2-\frac{1}{1-2\frac{GM}{rc^2}}dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta d\varphi^2.$$

So after a duration $T$ according to the clock of a rest observer far away from the planet, the proper time of an observer on the spaceship should have passed a time $$\tau_1=T\sqrt{1-2\frac{GM}{Rc^2}}.$$

The proper acceleration of the spaceship can be approximated by $\frac{GM}{R^2}$.

Second situation: a spaceship with rocket engine makes a trip in the empty space with a proper acceleration $a=\frac{GM}{R^2}$. The velocity of the spaceship according to a rest observer would be (after some calculations) $v=c\sqrt{\frac{(at)^2}{c^2+(at)^2}}$ as the function of the time $t$ from the moment the engine starts. And hence after a duration $T$ according to the clock of a rest observer, the proper time of an observer on the spaceship should have passed a time $$\tau_2=\int_0^Tdt\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}=\\\frac{c}{a}\ln\left(\frac{aT}{c}+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{aT}{c}\right)^2}\right).$$
(These calculations are done by considering at each instant $t$ the momentarily inertial frame moving with the spaceship).

The two results are different. Is it because the equivalence principle cannot be applied as such or because special relativity treatment on the second case is insufficient (what then would be a proper treatment?)?

Comment: The equations are the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The two results are different. Is it because the equivalence principle cannot be applied as such or because special relativity treatment on the second case is insufficient (what then would be a proper treatment?)

Remember that the equivalence principle applies "locally". The word "locally" in this context means that it applies within a region of spacetime that is small enough that you cannot detect tidal effects.

So when you say:

> according to the clock of a rest observer far away from the planet

You are no longer dealing with a local situation. Therefore the equivalence principle does not apply. To apply the equivalence principle you would need to compare the accelerating clocks to a nearby inertial clock, not a far away clock.

If you do that then you will find that they are indeed equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

According to the equivalence principle, it is not possible to say if we are static inside a gravitational field or accelerating in a region without gravity, for a small space-time interval, which requires not only a small space volume, but also a small time interval (otherwise tidal effects can be detected).

The crew inside the ship can suppose that a small proper time interval relates to the coordinates of a gravitational field with spherical symmetry, a given mass M and a given fixed distance from the centre, such that:$$\Delta \tau_1 = \Delta T\sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{Rc^2}}$$

Or that it relates to an inertial frame such that they have a velocity $v$ with respect to it. And they have an acceleration $$a = \frac{GM}{R^2}$$ such that:$$\Delta \tau_2 = \Delta T 
\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$

It is similar to measure a small distance on the Earth surface as $\Delta d^2 = \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2$ for a local Cartesian coordinates, or $\Delta d^2 = R^2(\Delta \theta^2 + cos^2(\theta)\Delta \phi^2)$ for $\theta$ being latitude, $\phi$ being longitude and $R$ being the earth radius. The Earth is locally flat.

Answer (score 0):

> The two results are different. Is it because the equivalence principle cannot be applied as such or because special relativity treatment on the second case is insufficient (what then would be a proper treatment?)?

You are applying the equivalence principle so wrong that it's hard to say anything about it. :) Seriously. Let's just say one thing: Acceleration has no effect on clocks.

If we create, using big and small carousels, equivalent downhills between the centers and the perimeters, then we have equivalent clock ticking rate differences between the centers and the perimeters.

"Equivalent downhills" means that between the centers and the perimeters we have the same potential differences, and the same relativistic kinetic energy differences, and the same clock ticking rate differences.

On big carousels acceleration is small.

Downhills created by gravity have the same effect on clocks as equivalent downhills created by carousels.

Note: The above is not an example of how to apply equivalence principle correctly. It is an example of how to apply the concept of equivalent downhills, in a case were the equivalence principle can not be applied.